# Global liquid variable available in custom filters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

I have built some custom filters in liquid.

The app i'm building them on has multiple sites which certain users should not be able to access. In my case I have an `appointments` model, scoped to a site, which has a `booking_reference`. I don't want users of a site being able to find appointments that don't belong to them

I can have the passed into the `render` liquid method and have it available within the template. This can then be passed into the filter. But this can be spoofed easily.

So my question is, how can i get a global variable available in my liquid filters.

Alternatively is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Update: I looked into the `Drop` class that liquid has and methods on that don't take arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this, for example
controller:

```
render :text => liquid.render( vars, 
    :registers => {:current_site => @current_site}
)
```

In place where you define fillter or tag:

```
context.registers[:current_site]
```

Comment: Does the filter have knowledge of the context? I know I can get it in the tags and blocks.

Comment: This works! This really should be documented somewhere! Do you have a real account I can award the bounty to?

Comment: Sorry, I don't known what mean "real account". This my real account )

Comment: :D it came up as User234872782312 or something like it.